# Check if variable corresponds with Enum

Tags: c#

Say I have `int val = 1;` What is the best way to check whether or not that value corresponds with an enum. Here is a sample enum:

```
public enum AlertType 
{ 
    Success=1, 
    Warning=2, 
    Error=3 
};
```

I'm looking for an answer that has the best maintainability.

Comment: Are you looking for Enum::IsDefined Method ??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you are looking for [Enum::IsDefined Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.isdefined.aspx)

> Returns an indication whether a constant with a specified value exists
>   in a specified enumeration.

**Updated:-**

Try something like this:-

```
 if(Enum.IsDefined(typeof(AlertType), val)) {}
```

Comment: This is the best answer. Please update your answer with the actual code: `if(Enum.IsDefined(typeof(AlertType), val)) {}`

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
Int32 val = 1;
if (Enum.GetValues(typeof(AlertType)).Cast<Int32>().Contains(val))
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can cast you `enum` choices to an `int` for that check :

```
const int val = 1;
if (val == (int)AlertType.Success)
{
    // Do stuff
}
else if (val == (int) AlertType.Warning)
{
    // Do stuff
}
else if (val == (int) AlertType.Error)
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

Comment: I know I can do that, I was wondering if there was a better way.

Comment: Then your question should mention you're looking for something else.

Comment: To be fair, he did specify he's looking for the _"best"_ way, not _"a"_ way. EDIT: Just realized it wasn't clear (because Internets), I was trying to be sarcastic: what is the "best" way anyway? Could be a bit subjective (especially based on requirements: most type-safe? most performant? simplest syntax?)

Comment: @apfunk Then include what you tried and your expected output. Can't read minds.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair Best is pretty vague. Best for readability? For performance time? For maintainability? For expansion?

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault: Yeah, I just edited my comment. Sorry about that; I _definitely_ wasn't clear. What I was thinking in my head did _not_ get translated to my words. :)

Comment: @Pierre, but this is a demonstrably verbose and poor solution.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair hahaha sorry totally did not get it was sarcastic. Damn you interwebz

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other solutions offered, here's another easy way to check:

```
Enum.GetName(typeof(AlertType), (AlertType)val) != null
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(AlertType), x))
{
    var enumVal = Enum.Parse(typeof(AlertType), x.ToString());
}
else
{
    //Value not defined
}
```

Comment: Once you know it exists, you can just cast `x` to `AlertType` with `(AlertType)x`.